# Are members of a structure allowed to be static ?

Tags: c, structure

```
#include<stdio.h>
struct str 
{ 
   static int a ;
    int b ;
 } s ;
int main()
{
static int p , k ;
printf("%d %d",sizeof(p),sizeof(s));
getchar();
return 0;
}
```

above code is giving errors . But if I redefine the first member of the structure to 'int' rather than 'static int' then it runs fine . Why static members are not allowed in the structure and what is its significance ?

Comment: static member inside struct will limit its scope but usually static member must be shared(based on its scope) and hence we cannot use it in struct.

Comment: C is not an object oriented language.  As such, it makes no sense to define C structures as "static."  Static means, that methods can be invoked on the class without instantiating an object.  Think math.tan(theta) here.  Why would I want to instantiate a math object?  I could just invoke the static tan method on the math class and get my one shot and done answer.  I've never dealt too much with w/e compiler you're using or if even structs are disallowed in gcc (c++).  Rest assured, the provided answer is why.  Rethink your problem or move onto C++.

Comment: @Dale, static in C++ isn't restricted to methods but also applies to data. I can think of a few situations where it would make sense to have a one-copy-per-type variable that's still part of the variable itself.

Comment: Yeah that's fine.  I can see math::PI doing that.  All I'm saying is, static doesn't make sense outside of an object oriented paradigm.  One does not instantiate C structs, one simply invokes C structs.

Comment: I was gonna say one doesn't allocate memory on the heap, but that's bullshit.  I'm rusty.  To tell the truth, now that I think about it, I'm having a hard time reasoning differently about a C struct than a C++ object.

Answer (score 7):

There's simply no such feature in C language. And there's no meaningful conceptual framework for such feature in C.

You see, in C++ terms, there's only one relevant difference between a `static` member variable and an ordinary global variable: the scope in which its name is declared and the corresponding naming syntax. A global variable could be called `a`, while a static member of the class would be called `SomeClass::a`. Besides scoped naming, there are no other differences. (I deliberately ignore other C++-specific features, like access control, since they don't exist in C and this question is really about C.)

In C language a struct type does not introduce its own scope. There's no such naming syntax as   `SomeStruct::a` in C language. For this reason there's simply no reason to have static members in structs. You can declare a global variable instead and achieve the same effect. Call your global variable `str_a` to convey the intent to "associate" it with `struct str` and just think of that variable as a pseudo-static member of `struct str`.

Formally speaking, one could do it the same way in C++, i.e. completely ignore this feature of C++ language and use global functions and variables instead of static function and variables inside classes. However, by doing that one would forsake all member access control features of C++. And these features are really worth having. C language has no access control features, meaning that in C one loses [almost] nothing.

Comment: Actually, I'm not so certain it would be non-meaningful, though I'm not so arrogant as to downvote for that :-) You could still get at the struct-level static by using the syntactic sugar of `s.a`, where `s` is an _instance_ of `struct str`, even without using the `::` variant - C++ already allows this, I think. That would give you the one-per-type nature rather than one-per-instance. I could see this as being useful.

Comment: @paxdiablo: Yes, you are right. However, I'd say that the underlying mechanism is still based on the fact that classes form their own scopes. In C++ one still needs to provide a separate definition for such static member, for example...

Comment: The one-per-type and the one-per-instance miss the point of what static truly means.  It has nothing to do with one per anything.  It's just a nice way of saying this logic or variable can be apart of a class without necessarily having to allocate space for said object.  I use them, personally, as one shot and done methods.  Or commonly as the interface to a factory method.

Answer (score 0):

The language just doesn't allow it. There's no deeper reason other than that it's not part of the design. You can always achieve the same behaviour with a separate global variable like this:

```
struct str
{
    int b;
} s;

int str_a;
```

Note that it would be something entirely different to have a *non*-static `int a;` inside your struct, which would be a distinct subelement of *every* object of type `struct str`.

(Note also that in C++, a language evolved from C, static class members do exist and behave exactly like the workaround I described above, only that the name of the global variable is tightly associated to the name of the class.)

Answer (score 0):

A static modifier is to declare your variable in the global scope in your file and a static modifier in a function creates a variable with a persistant value limited to the scope of this functions. And you can not share the value of this integer between your instances of your struct.
This is not and cannot be supported in C ;)

Why do you want to use a static member in a struct? maybe there is (there must be) a better soluation.

Answer (score 0):

No, not in C. I believe C++ can do this and it means there is *one* copy of `a` that is shared amongst all instances of the `struct str` structure.

If you want to do something similar in C, you have a few options (there may be more, I just can't think of them at the moment).

The first is to break out the common variable with something like:

```
int struct_str_static_a;
struct str {
    int b;
} s;
```

That way, there is only one copy of `a` shared by all instances of the structure - each instance still gets its own copy of `b`.

A slight modification to that is to introduce a pointer to that common variable and initialise the pointer:

```
int struct_str_static_a;
struct str {
    int *pA;
    int b;
} s;
:
s.pA = &struct_str_static_a;
```

Then you can use `*(s.pA)` where before you would have used `s.a`. Because every instance of `struct str` has its own `pA` pointer that points to a single `a`, that gives you a similar effect. However, it's a torturous road to follow.

The third option is to get yourself on the next ISO C working group and put this forward as a change to the language. However, that's going to require a fair bit of effort from yourself for the next ten years or so, probably not worth the effort :-)

Answer (score 0):

You have good answers here: http://cboard.cprogramming.com/c-programming/123691-static-variable-structure.html

generally speaking you don't have any gain from declaring it static, but if you still wish to it , you may migrate to c++ or declare the whole struct as static.